# Cannot get JWT (json web token) to work with Apple App Store Connect API in PHP

Tags: app-store-connect

I get a 401/Not Authorized return for my JTW using PHP with Apple's App Store Connect API.

Using php 7.1.3, I've tried various libraries and raw php (code below). I'm pretty sure the header and payload are fine and the problem is the signing of it, using the p8 private key file I downloaded from Apple. I have quadruple checked the kid, iss, and private key file.

```php
        // Create token header as a JSON string
        $header = json_encode([
            'typ' => 'JWT',
            'alg' => 'ES256',
            'kid' => '1234567980'
        ]);

        // Create token payload as a JSON string
        $payload = json_encode([
            'iss' => '12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012',
            'exp' => time()+60*10, // 20 minute max allowed
            'aud' => 'appstoreconnect-v1'
        ]);

        $base64UrlHeader = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($header), '+/', '-_'), '=');
        $base64UrlPayload = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($payload), '+/', '-_'), '=');
        $privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://'.resource_path('/assets/AppleKey_1234567980.p8'));
        $signature = '';
        openssl_sign("$base64UrlHeader.$base64UrlPayload", $signature, $privateKey, 'sha256');

        // Encode Signature to Base64Url String
        $base64UrlSignature = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($signature), '+/', '-_'), '=');

        // Create JWT
        $jwt = "$base64UrlHeader.$base64UrlPayload.$base64UrlSignature";
```

When I submit this to Apple via curl, I get a 401/Not Authorized with details "Authentication credentials are missing or invalid" and nothing more specific.

Has anyone used Apple's App Store Connect API with PHP - google searches have slim to no results I can find.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this solution. i manage to get authenticated and get data from appleconnect. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57150060/860353